# Padding with spaces in char array

Tags: c++, character-arrays

I am writing a program to write a head for a specific image format. This image format requires 256 characters as its header before any following raw image data. But I have problem padding empty spaces to make the header 256 characters long.

Below is an abstraction of my problem:

```
char pad[256];
sprintf( pad, "header info:%s=%f", "scale", 2.3);
cout<<pad<<"data here"<<endl;
```

The output is:

```
header info:scale=2.300000data here
```

However, the result I expect is like:

```
header info:scale=2.300000                            data here
```

where "data here" appears after 256 characters from the beginning of the file.
How can I change the program to pad empty spaces in the character array?

Comment: Does it help that sprintf returns the number of characters written?

Comment: @PeterSchneider Sorry, I don't catch what you mean.

Comment: What if you did: `std::memset(&arr[0], 0x20, 256);` or `std::fill(&arr[0], &arr[256], 0x20);` then wrote to the array after? Whatever parts you did not write to will be spaces. Kind of like initialising the array with spaces and overwriting whatever parts with relevant data.

Comment: sprintf returns the number of characters written, not counting the zero byte. From there on you can assign spaces to the array elements, till you hit 255. Do not forget to terminate the string with 0 (you probably need pad[257]).

Comment: @Brandon: sprintf() terminates with a zero char.

Comment: @PeterSchneider; What? I was just suggesting another way instead of `sprintf`. For example, in C I usually initialise my arrays with 0's. Then I write to them. This way, I never have to really worry about terminating them. Similarly, OP could fill his/her array with spaces and then write to it. The unwritten parts will be spaces.

Comment: @Brandon I tried putting `fill(&pad[0], &pad[256], 0x20);` and `memset(&pad[0], 0x20, 256);` before sprintf(), but it didn't work.

Comment: @Brandon: "OP could fill his/her array with spaces and then write to it. The unwritten parts will be spaces." If "writing" means using sprintf, then there will be a terminating 0 character after "2.300000". _There_after will be spaces, yes, but no string function would "see", e.g. output them.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Do you mean manually adding spaces inside quotes? If the floating number appears as 2.300000, is it eight character length?

Comment: Read carefully my first and second comment. Look up the return value of sprintf. Think for yourself.

Comment: Like this: http://ideone.com/lBBJnT  @PeterSchneider yeah you are right about it null-terminating. I thought OP would know what to do from there. Even simpler: http://ideone.com/NaKgOv

Comment: @Brandon right, strlen() is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
cout << setw(256) << left << pad << "data here" <<endl;
```

You may need `#include <iomanip>`.

BTW in your "real code" you should use `snprintf` to ensure there is no chance of a buffer overflow, assuming that your `%s` is going to get some argument that's worked out at runtime . (Or preferably replace the `sprintf` with a stringstream).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. The format `-` which left aligns the text. For example, the following will left align the float text with a fixed width of 20. The default space character is used as padding.

```
sprintf( pad, "header info:%s=%-20f", "scale", 2.3);
```